# Vector notation in 3 dimension

Tags: calculus, vector-analysis

I know the title might not be the most accurate but i don't really know how else to title it.

[image]

Question is, why is $r'=Rcos\phi'+Rsin\phi'$

Second question: [image]

Here my text book mentioned that $r'cos\alpha = \hat{r} \cdot r'$, why is this?

Comment: It seems like they forgot the basis vectors $\mathbf{\hat{x}}$ and $\mathbf{\hat{y}}$ in the formula for $\mathbf{r}'$.